# Where I can find(if it exists) the voice "CSS class suffix" for "body" in Joomla panel?

Tags: css, joomla, suffix, html-tbody

I'm trying to add a class to change padding-top of the body of a site. Put the style definition in the CSS is not a problem, I've found it from Chrome inspector and I've also tested the whole setting on it. The main problem is to put the suffix of that class from the joomla panel, without modifyng the main html file.
I want to add it as if it was a Joomla module, I wonder if it is possible.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the menu entry, if I understand your question correctly.
You have to go to *Menus*, select the Menu that holds the page you want to edit, e.g. *Main Menu*, select the menu entry you want to edit, e.g. *Home*.

Under the *Page Display* tab you'll find a *Page Class* text input, where you can define your class (note that you'll probably need to enter it with leading blank, e.g. " custom_class")